# How to use import in JavaScript without side effects or executing through anything else?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

When I use `import { export } from "module-name";`, how do I make sure that it doesn't also run `import "module-name";` for side effects?

In other words, how do I make JavaScript only look at the export and ignore everything else in the file when importing the export into another file.

For example:

I want to print only "foo".

**B.js:**

// start here

```
import {foo} from "./A.js";
foo();
```

**A.js**

```
export function foo() {
   console.log("foo");
}
console.log("IN A");
```

Comment: What should happen in the case A.js is `var bar = nonPureFunction(); export function foo() { return bar; }`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what that code is trying to do.

Comment: He's asking why you'd want to import potentially completely broken JS. An export may depend on other things in the file. Ignoring parts of JS files means things may be broken.

Comment: My point is that the exported value may be dependent on other code hat runs in the module (and that code may have side effects like logging). How do you hope to solve the problem that the creation of  the export might necessarily come after some other (potentially side-effect-causing?) code?

Comment: What if the function is a pure function then?

Comment: How would `import` know that?

Comment: Is there a way to use it in another file in the method I want then? I don't have to use import.

Comment: ... Rewrite it?

Comment: So I would have to write a duplicate function in each file I use it in? That doesn't seem very efficient.

Comment: I think @Dave's point is that the only way to ensure your code doesn't have side effects is: don't write or use code that has side effects. There is no generalized way to "turn off"  a function's side effects. You could, perhaps, algorithmically determine that a given function does or does not have side effects by introspecting the function's code, but this is a complex exercise in CS theory: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/176761/compute-if-a-function-is-pure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how do I make JavaScript only look at the export and ignore everything else in the file when importing the export into another file.

This is in the general case not a well-defined goal, because the exported value may be been created (in full or in part) by the output of a side-effect-causing function. Consider the following module:

```
var bar;
if(Math.random() > 0.5) {
    bar = console.log("bar is undefined");
} else {
    bar = new Date();
}

export function foo() {
    console.log(bar);
}
```

The entire point of the `foo` function here is to log `bar`, but in order to learn what `bar` is, we must pass through a minefield of non-pure operations. Asking for only the exported function `foo` without running the non-pure code that generates `bar` doesn't make any sense -- the behavior of `foo` depends entirely on the value of `bar`.

If you wish for `A.js` to have no side effects, the solution here is to (re)write the code of `A.js` so it produces no side effects.